# Как сделать редирект с с https://lakiremont.ru//// на https://lakiremont.ru?

Tags: php, редирект

Пробовал с помощью этого:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Но, ничего не вышло. Подскажите в чем дело?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)\/{2,}(.*?)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Мой конфиг

```
# redirect from site.com/index.php to site.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect from www.site.com to site site.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

#remove double slashes
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /{2,}
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect from site.com/ to site site.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\&
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![^\/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```